# Clicking on button in whatsapp web using javascript

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I've the following code. What I'm trying to do is hover over the msg-container (message, on whatsapp web), click on the triangle context button that appears, and click on "Download"

I'm trying to automate downloading voice messages (the only messages that have download button on them are voice messages or media I think, and also I'm executing this code when "starred messages" tab is open)

But for some reason, it only hovers over the message, the triangle appears, it clicks on it but then it doesn't click on the download button.

I know this is really specific but to reproduce this you can star 2 or 3 voice messages on whatsapp web, go to starred messages tab on the browser, open the console and paste the code.

```
var messageContainers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="msg-container"]');
for (var i = 0; i < messageContainers.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(container) {
    // Simulate a mouseover event on the container element
    var mouseoverEvent = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true
    });
    container.dispatchEvent(mouseoverEvent);

    // Wait for the "down context" button to appear, then simulate a click event on it
    setTimeout(function() {
      var tri = container.querySelector('[data-testid="icon-down-context"]');
      if (tri) {
        var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
          view: window,
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true
        });
        tri.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

        // Wait for the download button to appear, then simulate a click event on it
        setTimeout(function() {
          var downloadButton = container.querySelector('[data-testid="mi-msg-download"]');
          if (downloadButton) {
            downloadButton.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
          }
        }, 1000);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000 * i, messageContainers[i]);
}
```

Comment: You probably won't be able to it this way. 1. Any web app can distinguish a sintetic event from a user triggered.  2. The code depends on other actions outside of you control with js from the console. What you probably need is a automation/scraping tool like puppeteer or playwright.

Comment: I'll look into it, but I don't understand why I'm able to hover and click on the first 2 elements but not on the 3rd one...
edit: I have little to no knowledge about coding. I looked into both puppeteer and playwright, and they both seem to be only source codes that I need to build myself (?)

Comment: I just wanted to automate downloading audio files because there's maybe 200+ and I'll take a lot of time if done manually. (can't edit the comment anymore so I had to make a new comment)

Comment: Some controls might accept sintetic events others don't. But that might not be the issue. I am just guessing here. My point is that if you want to automate what's app behavior u likely won't achieve it from the devtools console. People use browser automation for that.

Comment: You need to run playwright on nodejs. For that u need to install the packages locally with npm. But also configure the test runner to keep sessions so it opens and it keeps all you cookies and data persisted. Otherwise u will need to sync to the phone every seesion. It is not an easy thing to do if u are not familiar with nodejs.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try Cypress. They have a great free course: https://learn.cypress.io/

Answer (score 1):

For some reason this one worked. Just in case if anyone else needs it.

```
var messageContainers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="msg-container"]');
for (var i = 0; i < messageContainers.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(container) {
    // Simulate a mouseover event on the container element
    var mouseoverEvent = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true
    });
    container.dispatchEvent(mouseoverEvent);
    setTimeout(function() {
    // Find the triangle element and simulate a click event on it
        var tri = container.querySelector('[data-testid="down-context"]');
        if (tri) {
      
        var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
          view: window,
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true
        });
        tri.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

        // Wait for the context menu to appear
        setTimeout(function() {
          // Find the download button and simulate a click event on it
          var downloadButton = document.querySelector('li[data-testid="mi-msg-download"] > div._1MZM5');
          if (downloadButton) {
            downloadButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
              view: window,
              bubbles: true,
              cancelable: true
            }));
          }
        }, 500);
        }
        },500);
  }, 1000 * i, messageContainers[i]);
}
```

Comment: are you talking about web.whatsapp.com ? Mine dont have any of these `data-testid`. Or has it changed recently ?

Comment: @ishandutta2007 I don't actually know since I did this almost a year ago. It could have been changed but I've been informed that doing this is not the correct way to do it (or the optimal) You can use browser emulations using python.

Comment: What's the correct way that you have moved on to ? selenium, puppeteer etc ... ?

Comment: @ishandutta2007 on top of those, Playwright is also an option. But unfortunately I won't be able to give much information because after the code I provided above worked for me at the time, I didn't have any needs for browser automation afterwards. This was a one time thing I did and it's probably outdated now.